# Unable to import java.io into a scala package in a mixed scala/java project

Tags: scala, maven

I have a mixed scala/java project.  Why would the following import not work?

[image]

This error occurs both in Intellij and more importantly on `maven` command line using

```
  mvn clean -DskipTests package
```

Here is the intellij SDK:

[image]

Here is the relevant section of the `pom.xml` showing the java/scala interaction - as recommended by https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/example_java.html :

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.1.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
                    <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Here is the error from `maven` command line:

```
[ERROR] /git/OCspark/tcpclient/src/main/scala/com/pointr/tcp/iotest/package.scala:2: object io is not a member of package com.pointr.tcp.java
[ERROR] import java.io._
[ERROR]             ^
```

**Update** Based on a comment by @ LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I looked at the `java` sources. Note that `java` is *not* the root of the package hierarchy  - which might have then been the more obvious cause of this problem:

[image]

But .. unmarking_ the java directory as sources does fix the problem..

[image]

Why would this fix it?

Comment: Which error do you get?
Which **jdk** version are you using for compiling that code?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez yes I was adding the error when you commented ;)  The jdk version is shown in the `pom.xml` above as 1.8

Comment: The error message is somewhat clear. You have another object / package called java in scope. There are many solutions, like renaming or hiding, but a pretty simple one is to import from the root package: `import _root_.java.io._.`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez  You're on to something here..  I have updated the question with a follow-up.

Comment: sorry, I was not clear. As you can see, on your java sources you define a package called `com.pointr.tcp.java`. And as you are trying to import the `io` package from java, the parser believes you are referring to the same `java` package that you defined. To fix the problem, you can: 1. Rename that java package to something else. 2. Hide that package: `import java => _` before `import java.io`. 3. Import using the fully qualified name `import _root_.java.io._` _(`_root_` is a reserved keyword of the language, that always refers to the root of the packages hierarchy)_.

Comment: UR correct on this.  I never ran into this problem before - after 5.5 years as scala my primary language and tens of K's of sloc.   Why would this only surface now and for _java_ as the prefix?

Comment: The package being called `java` here is irrelevant, the problem is the ambiguity of the packages names. I once have the same problem with `import fs2.io` and then `import io.circe.Decoder`. In general, I do not expect this to be that common, as usually people try to do not reuse names for top-level package names.

Comment: Feel free to make an answer - it seems the takeaway were "scala can and will try to find partial matches on your class hierarchy".  I did not know that